# Androidx libraries for Xamarin.Android in Visual Studio NuGet

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, nuget, androidx

Are the `androidx` libraries available in Visual Studio's NuGet package manager?

My app is targeting Android P so I can use the androidx libraries in Android Studio but I can't find them in NuGet.

With Android Studio I can use:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

but throws exception in Visual Studio:

```
02-09 21:31:59.970 I/MonoDroid( 8843): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
02-09 21:32:00.137 I/MonoDroid( 8843): Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/Keystore.Keystore-aaHeQkjsNRoUnkfPmnf7Tw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/Keystore.Keystore-aaHeQkjsNRoUnkfPmnf7Tw==/lib/x86, /data/app/Keystore.Keystore-aaHeQkjsNRoUnkfPmnf7Tw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
02-09 21:32:00.137 I/MonoDroid( 8843):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
02-09 21:32:00.137 I/MonoDroid( 8843):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
02-09 21:32:00.137 I/MonoDroid( 8843):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in <8acc8089c2ed40d08469fbaa6710a44c>:0 
02-09 21:32:00.137 I/MonoDroid( 8843):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <8acc8089c2ed40d08469fbaa6710a44c>:0 
02-09 21:32:00.137 I/MonoDroid( 8843):   at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (System.Int32 layoutResID) [0x00022] in <957bbfdfda4341e2939c881206c1140a>:0 
02-09 21:32:00.137 I/MonoDroid( 8843):   at Keystore.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00009] in H:\My Projects\Android\Samples\Keystore\MainActivity.cs:19 
02-09 21:32:00.137 I/MonoDroid( 8843):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <957bbfdfda4341e2939c881206c1140a>:0 
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.3(intptr,intptr,intptr)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):   --- End of managed Android.Views.InflateException stack trace ---
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/Keystore.Keystore-aaHeQkjsNRoUnkfPmnf7Tw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/Keystore.Keystore-aaHeQkjsNRoUnkfPmnf7Tw==/lib/x86, /data/app/Keystore.Keystore-aaHeQkjsNRoUnkfPmnf7Tw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at md561c0eefc2ba1e38323457d81b00d3caf.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at md561c0eefc2ba1e38323457d81b00d3caf.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
02-09 21:32:00.138 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
02-09 21:32:00.139 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
02-09 21:32:00.139 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
02-09 21:32:00.139 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
02-09 21:32:00.139 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
02-09 21:32:00.139 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
02-09 21:32:00.139 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
02-09 21:32:00.139 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-09 21:32:00.139 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
02-09 21:32:00.139 I/MonoDroid( 8843):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

So is there a way to use the `androidx` libraries with Xamarin.Android?

Comment: If i am not wrong you are trying to add the ConstraintLayout if yes check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it is finally available https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androidx-for-xamarin/

The NuGet list [is here.](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22AndroidX%22+Authors%3A%22Microsoft%22)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot find it is because you must not have its NuGet

We need to add `Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout` package to support ConstraintLayout in our Xamarin.Android project. So to add this package right click on

**Packages > Add Packages.**   //MAC

**References -> Manage NuGet Packages** //Windows

Search for `ConstraintLayout` and add a package by accepting a licence.

And use the following namespace `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>` in XML

**Update**

In my knowledge `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` is unavailable in Mono.Droid and hence you might have to bind it to an AAR and then use that AAR to make a [Xamarin Binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) fix the issues that happen while making that binding and then use it into your Droid project as a .dll

Comment: I have its NuGet, version 1.1.2 and `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` works but I wanted to know if we can use the `androidx` one. Also we have to right click on **References -> Manage NuGet Packages...**

Comment: I don't think that is available! I actually use a mac so for me its add packages! But you could bind its aar into xamarin if you have it!